# Different Jmeter Exception with Ultimate Thread

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I have the following Ultimate Thread 120 VUs(see screenshot) which failed with the following 2 messages :

- 1-bzm - Streaming Sampler - master,Non HTTP response code: **javax.net.ssl.SSLException,Non HTTP response message**: Received close_notify during handshake,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group
- 2- bzm - Streaming Sampler - master,Non HTTP response code: **org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException,Non HTTP response message**: damxdcfpo.maxdome.de:443 failed to respond,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group

[image]

And the same test Sceanrio with 40 Thread works well  (screenshot)

[image]

where can be the problem?

Playlist URL:

- https://damxdcfpo.maxdome.de/mxd-manifest-service/mxd-mediavault-prod/0e729a_14877308_2017-09-07_21-35/14877308.ism/.mpd?session_id=1007560909-1171643860-29cdf&filter=(type==%22video%22%26%26MaxHeight%3C=720)%7C%7C(type==%22audio%22%26%26FourCC==%22AACL%22)
- BZM-Streaming Sampler video Duration:12seconds
- Jmeter Verison: 5.2.1
- HLS Pluging Version : 3.0.1
- Java Version :java version "1.8.0_91" Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the server you're testing gets overloaded and cannot handle 120 virtual users.

Next steps you could do is:

1. Find the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) (the point of maximum system performance) by looking into metrics like [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime), [Response Times over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime), [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond).

   Ideally response time should remain steady and the transactions per second should increase by the same factor as the number of virtual users. When response time starts growing - it indicates the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)
2. Find the reason for the system not being handle 120 concurrent users which might be in:

   - Insufficient resources (CPU, RAM, slow Network or Disks), it can be checked using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
   - Incorrect application and middleware configuration like default values which are good for development but not good for production, missing caching, etc. i.e. check [How To Setup Nginx For HLS Video Streaming On Centos 7](https://dev.to/samuyi/how-to-setup-nginx-for-hls-video-streaming-on-centos-7-3jb8)
   - A bug in the application code like using [inefficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), it can be checked using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)